# how to access an arraylist with json objects in a repeat control

Tags: arrays, json, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I am trying something new. I want to pass an arraylist with json objects via the property definition in a custom control. the property I called cols and is of type object.

On an xpage i have calculated the value of the property now as followed:

```
<xc:this.cols><![CDATA[#{javascript:var cols = [];

cols.push({ 
        "colName" : "Petter",
        "colValue"  : "Developer"
    });
cols.push({ 
        "colName" : "Jesper",
        "colValue"  : "Administrator"
    });
return cols;}]]></xc:this.cols>
```

Now in my repeater I want to use these objects/values. But I am not sure how?

First I tried outside my repeat control just how to access them in JavaScript e.g.:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var cols = compositeData.cols;

cols[0]["colValue"]}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var cols = compositeData.cols;

cols[1]["colValue"]}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
```

This seems to work because I get the values Developer and Administrator returned.

Now I want to access the json in my repeat control but I get lost here.

Here is how I have set up my repeat control:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="colObj" indexVar="idx"
            value="#{javascript:compositeData.cols}">
```

Then I have placed a computed text control within my repeat control and try something similar:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:colObj[idx]["colValue"]}]]></xp:this.value>
             </xp:text>
```

But then I get an error:

com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)

Can someone explain what I have done wrong and how I should do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:colObj[idx]["colValue"]}]]>    
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

To this:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:colObj["colValue"]}]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

You alreadyb have the colObj so, no need to get the subset.  The repeat control deals with the idx so, `colObj` in the repeat is the same as `colObj[n]` outside the repeat.

Comment: hello Rob. the index is provided for me indeed. thank you!